# Find a vector parametrization of the circle contained in the plane x=5 with radius 3 centered at the point (5,1,2)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, circles, parametrization

I know the vector parametrization of the circle contained within the yz-plane centered at the origin is:

$\vec r$( $\theta$ ) = < 0, 3 cos $\theta$ , 3 sin $\theta$ >

What do I do next?
If the circle was contained in the xy-plane or xz-plane, how would this change the parametrization?

Comment: It's worth noting that this question as stated doesn't quite make sense; a circle contained in the plane $x=5$ has its center in the same plane, so its center could never be $(3,1,2)$. @AbdallahHammam's answer is one reasonable interpretation, but note that the resulting circle doesn't have radius $3$.

Comment: @stewbasic My bad. I meant to put the point (5,1,2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle we want the parametrization for, which is the intersection of the sphere of equation

$$(x-5)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2=9$$

with  the plane $x=5$ has equation

$$(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2=9.$$

Thus, we can parametrize the circle in the following way:

\begin{align}
    x&=5\\
    y&=1+3\cos(t)\\
    z&=2+3\sin(t).\\
\end{align}